# How do I deliver templates arguments to templated sub-class via inheritance?

Tags: c++

I have this code that uses a template parent class `A` that has one templated sub-class `C`. `A` takes a type (`T`) and `C` takes an object of that type (`T t`) in their template parameters. What I'm trying to do is, in the inheritance of the class `B`, give `C` its template arguments, make a `b` object, and call `C`'s `.h` member function. But I'm getting the following errors:

> prog.cpp:10:44: error: too many template-parameter-lists
>   prog.cpp: In function `'int main()'`:
>   prog.cpp:14:5: error: `'B'` was not declared in this scope
>   prog.cpp:14:7: error: expected `';'` before `'b'`

```
template <typename T> struct A {
    protected:
        template <T> struct C { 
            T h( T t ) { return t * t; }
        };
};

template <typename T = int> template <T t = 5> struct B : public A<T>::C<t> {};

int main() {

    B b;
    b.h();

}
```

The error is called when I instantiate a `B` object. I've tried changing a lot of things around but it didn't help the situation. For example, I changed:

```
template <typename T = int> template <T t = 5> struct B...
```

to

```
template <typename T = int> struct B...
```

and changed

```
: public A<T>::C<t> {};
```

to

```
: public A<T>::C<T t = 5> {};
```

But I received even more errors:

> prog.cpp:10:53: error: non-template `'C'` used as template
>   prog.cpp:10:53: note: use `'A<T>::template C'` to indicate that it is a template
>   prog.cpp:10:66: error: expected `'{'` before `';'` token
>   prog.cpp: In function `'int main()`:
>   prog.cpp:14:7: error: missing template arguments before `'b'`
>   prog.cpp:14:7: error: expected `';'` before `'b'`

I'm also curious about the first set of errors in which I got `B was not declared in this scope`. How could it not be? Is it the way I'm defining `B`? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: How do you derive from a base class that is not visible because it is protected?

Comment: @Nobody I get the same errors whether it's protected or not.

Comment: It was just a side node that would not solve the problem but show another. Also I do not see why you template C as you do not use the template parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make 2 changes to your code:

```
// First you don't need and should not use 2 templates
template <typename T = int, T t = 5> struct B
    // C++ doesn't know that A<T>::C is a template so you should say it here
    : public A<T>::template C<t> {};
```

Comment: @David: Even when all template parameters are set by default values you have to specify the angle braces. Write `B<> b;`.

Comment: @David: the first error is because `C` is protected within `A`, so `B`, which isn't derived from `A`, cannot access it. The second error is because `h` requires an argument, but you don't provide one in `main`.